# Move textview with animation till performin zoom out or zoom in animation

Tags: java, android, animation, textview

I have this animation for zoom out the text the problem is there when I zoom out the text is in the middle of the text view after this I am using following code to resize the view and the text is leaved in the middle and is partly not visible I want to move the text up so to can be visible in the resized text view any help will be good I am new to Android so plase help.:

Animation:

```
<scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="0.5"
    android:toYScale="0.5">
</scale>
```

TextView resize code.

```
    public static void slideView(View view,
                             int currentHeight,
                             int newHeight) {

    ValueAnimator slideAnimator = ValueAnimator
            .ofInt(currentHeight, newHeight)
            .setDuration(800);

    /* We use an update listener which listens to each tick
     * and manually updates the height of the view  */

    slideAnimator.addUpdateListener(animation1 -> {
        Integer value = (Integer) animation1.getAnimatedValue();
        view.getLayoutParams().height = value.intValue();
        view.requestLayout();
    });

    /*  We use an animationSet to play the animation  */

    AnimatorSet animationSet = new AnimatorSet();
    animationSet.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    animationSet.play(slideAnimator);
    animationSet.start();
}
```

TextView properties:

```
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/t1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
    android:text="How to make french toast"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cons1" />
```

Comment: Can you tell me more in details about animations...

Comment: The problem is when I resize text view the text inside resize also

Comment: I mean it clip the half of the text

Comment: You mean text can not full zoom in or out..?? it scale to half of screen??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73918703/text-on-textview-is-cliping-on-half-on-animation-android

Comment: take a look of this question