# Text on textview is cliping on half on animation Android

Tags: java, android, textview, android-animation, android-linearlayout

So my problem is, I use animation to resize text in text view and move it a bit. When I resize the LinearLayout Layout text is clipping to half if it's long text how can I stay in bound so to not clip my text when I resize the LinearLayout

Text view is in Liner layout and parent is Constrant layout.

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cons1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/t1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
        android:text="How to make french toast"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cons1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Scroll view listener to change on scrolling

```
    scrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
        boolean isStart = false;

        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
            if (scrollY > 0 && !isStart) {
                recipeTitle.startAnimation(animZoomOut);
                slideView(layout2, layout2.getHeight(), layout2.getHeight() / 2);

                isStart = true;
            } else if (scrollY <= 0) {
                slideView(layout2, layout2.getHeight(), layout2.getHeight() * 2);
                recipeTitle.startAnimation(animZoomIn);
                isStart = false;

            }

        }
    });
```

Method to resize textview,

```
public static void slideView(View view,
                             int currentHeight,
                             int newHeight) {

    ValueAnimator slideAnimator = ValueAnimator
            .ofInt(currentHeight, newHeight)
            .setDuration(1000);

    /* We use an update listener which listens to each tick
     * and manually updates the height of the view  */

    slideAnimator.addUpdateListener(animation1 -> {
        Integer value = (Integer) animation1.getAnimatedValue();
        view.getLayoutParams().height = value.intValue();
        view.requestLayout();
    });

    /*  We use an animationSet to play the animation  */

    AnimatorSet animationSet = new AnimatorSet();
    animationSet.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    animationSet.play(slideAnimator);
    animationSet.start();
}
```

anim xml files

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true">

<scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="0.5"
    android:toYScale="0.5">
</scale>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="0%p" android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toXDelta="-28%p" android:toYDelta="-28%p"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fillAfter="true" />
```